# How to segregate objects in an array list using java

Tags: java

I have Persons objects with `P1{Salary,Tax,'C or D'}` inside a list. Want to do below two things 
1. Segregate all the Person objects into one person object(any one of existing Person object) where  salary of this person object will be sum of all the salaries of person objects whose "CreditOrDebit" flag is 'C'. And want to add this to an ArrayList.
2.Want to add all the remaining Person Objects with "CreditOrDebit" flag as 'D' to the array list (which I used to add in point 1)

Here's the example:

```
Class Person{
int sal,tax;
String CreditOrDebit;
//with setters and getters
}
```

Ex: **Input**:

```
Person1(1000, 10,"C");
Person2(4000, 15,"D");
Person3(6000, 15,"D");
Person4(8000, 10,"C");
Person5(5000, 10,"C");
```

**Output**:

```
New Person1(4000, 15, "D")
New Person2(6000, 15, "D")
New Person3(14000, 10, "C")
```

What I need is an more efficient code than this. As this piece of code i am using in lot many places in my project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "more efficient code than this"? Have you actually profiled your application and found that this (the constructor calls?) is a bottleneck?

Comment: Not about constructor calls. It’s about better pseudo code if any. Or you can review same code. Thanks for prompt reply

Comment: I cannot figure out the relationship between the input and output. Why do 2 of them disappear? Where does the 4000 come from for the third item? Why is the output "`New`"? What does the number mean in "Person1", "Person2" etc?

Comment: @AndyTurner its a typo-its 14000(sum of all Cs)

Comment: @Sammetanagasrinivas then [edit] the question to fix the typo.

Comment: @FarazDurrani  a new Person object which is a sum of all salaries (14000) of all ‘C’s and all the ‘D’s as it is.

Comment: @FarazDurrani  new person meaning-one person object of all ‘C’s added (can you check my answer code once)and remaining ‘D’s.

Comment: @FarazDurrani need  code also in java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it Java 8's functional style:

```
int sumOfC
= persons.stream()
.filter(person -> person.getCreditOrDebit().equals("C"))
.mapToInt(person -> person.getSalary()).sum();
```

then,

```
Person p = new Person(sumOfC, tax, "C");
```

And same thing you can do for`D`

Java 7 style:

```
int sumOfC = 0;
for (Person person : persons) {
    if (person.getCreditOrDebit().equals("C")){
        sum += person.getSalary();
    }
}
Person p = new Person(sumOfC, tax, "C");
```

Answer (score 3):

For a solution that could do the sum for each type of transaction, you could use `Collectors.groupingBy`. This works just like an SQL group by. You specify the "key" and the function for the grouping your want. Following, I will group by `type` and sum the `salary`:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(new Person(1000, "C"));
persons.add(new Person(500, "D"));
persons.add(new Person(100, "C"));
persons.add(new Person(1500, "C"));
persons.add(new Person(750, "D"));

Map<String, Integer> result = persons.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getType, //group by type
                    Collectors.summingInt(Person::getSalary))); //sum salary

System.out.println(result);
```

> {C=2600, D=1250}

The part about creating a new `Person` is easy enough. Just need to iterate the `Map` and build an new instance :

```
List<Person> summary = result.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new Person(e.getValue(), e.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(summary);
```

Note that this is not an information that should be in `Person`. The instance name don't make sense here... you should correct that.

This used the following class description :

```
class Person {
    int salary;
    String type;

    public Person(int salary, String type) {
        super();
        this.salary = salary;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi..but i do not want to group using ‘D’ .

Comment: Trust me @Sammetanagasrinivas, at some point, someone will view this question _"How to segregate objects in an array list using java"_ and will need to. And you might too because I don't see the point to sum the credit operation without doing the same on the debit operation... so remember that this is possible for the futur ;)